# Whats the best desktop share/vnc for local network?

Tags: network, wifi, vpn, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I have two Macs on the same network, I want to control one of them headless from the other. I have tried the built-in remote management but it is so slow it is un-usable. The connection between them is fine 5ghz wifi full speed but the lag is incredible.

Is there a VNC (or other protocol) that would work better in real time? Also, another few desired features not supported by built in screenshare. Would be awesome if one of the Macs could be connected to VPN and this still work. Finally I would like to use the mic/camera from main mac on the headless mac if at all possible.

Comment: Have you tried over Ethernet rather than wifi? I use Remote Desktop day in, day out with no issues. You wouldn't want to play a 1st person shooter on it, but it's perfectly usable. I can actually watch movies over it.

Comment: The router is not near the desktop so not possible unless it was a direct connection. However, I have no issues on this wifi setup playing VR games with virtual desktop so I know there should be no issues with input lag between these two.